# FaceDetector cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, opencv, exception, face

I'm trying to build a detector for face detection in images. I use the OpenCV library, version 2.4.11.

Now my source code looks like following :

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class DetectFaces {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath());
        Mat image = Highgui
                .imread(FaceDetector.class.getResource("pic.JPG").getPath());

        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

      //  System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));

        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                    new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }

        String filename = "ouput.png";
       // System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
        Highgui.imwrite(filename, image);
    }
}
```

Now I get an `FaceDetector cannot be resolved to a type` exception every time `FaceDetector.class` is called.

While working on this implementation I am following the [tutorial](https://blog.openshift.com/day-12-opencv-face-detection-for-java-developers/)

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thank You

Comment: is it in the same package as `DetectFaces` class?

Comment: You didn't read, and copy-paste, the tutorial correctly. The class you are writing _is_ named `FaceDetector`, not `DetectFaces`...!

Comment: @Tunaki. You are right, thanks. But how is this a dublicate to the topic you have linked?

Comment: Because it explains everything that can cause the error you're having. One of them being that you typed the name incorrectly.

Comment: Now after following your advice and changing the name I get a Null Pointer Exception in the following line: DetectFaces.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath()

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgotten to import the class?
Or is it in the same folder?